# Android: SurfaceView stops drawing on a third finger

Tags: java, android, touch, multi-touch, motion-detection

The following code is the actual code used in an test app, on a class that extends surfaceView.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{       
    canvas.drawCircle(touched_x, touched_y, 50, myPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    touched_x = event.getX();
    touched_y = event.getY();  
    return true;    
}
```

**It basically draws where your finger goes.** To test if its tracking or not.

**Adding a second finger, and you can still tracks your first. But add a 3rd, and it just stops.** It doesnt matter what you do from there. Unless you remove all fingers and start again it wont track.

Now this is a problem since it sometimes thinks one finger is three! I can overcome this testing distance between fingers, but still, this doesnt resolve the problem.

When the third finger hits and it freezes tracking. It doesnt invoke action.Cancel.

**Its vital that I know where and when the 1st finger is released.**

However it thinks the last event was `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`. Not `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL`.

Currently since one finger can be three. My app just will seem like it failed to load a given image scroll.

Comment: can you show your code where you handle 3 finger touch?

Comment: I dont handle it, I dont care for the 3rd finger. Except that it is stopping the first finger.

Answer (score 0):

post more of your code. I'm not getting any problems. Maybe you forgot to invalidate view in some cases or there is a mistake?
There is my full code and it works:

```
float x1 = -100, y1;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawCircle(x1, y1, 30, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    x1 = event.getX();
    y1 = event.getY();

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Maybe you have [bugs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5puAvPqXpuc&feature=related) on your device, but that's unlikely..

Comment: Im using the One X. It works fine on Samsung tablet. Might well be a bug.